# Using an VB6 DLL from c++

Tags: c++, dll, vb6

I have an Activex DLL created in visual basic 6.0 and iwant to call it from visual c++ 6.0

Can any one help me, how to use an VB6 DLL from c++?

Answer (score 1):

1. Register the component with regsvr32.
2. Import it into your code with `#import "MyActiveX.dll"`.

The documentation for `#import` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx).

Comment: if i have thi function in my DLL

Public function addNumber(x As Integer, y As Integer)
    addNumber=x+y
End Function

how to use this function in c++?

Comment: That's an entirely different question. You asked how to use an ActiveX. Either the DLL is an ActiveX, or it isn't. If it isn't then you've asked the wrong question. If it isn't you'll want to use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress. Or create a .lib file and a C++ header file and import that way.

Comment: @cahyo16 Exporting a flat native function from a VB6 dll is possible with a little bit of dark magic (in case your function is trivial and does not really call into the VB6 runtime) or a really good deal of dark magic in case your function is anything beyond being absolutely trivial. The short answer is "Don't do this". If you ever find yourself at *that* level of understanding how VB6 runtime works internally, you won't need to ask any questions.